# Bad request sending GET request with id (ExpressJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mean

Using MEAN.JS. Routes:

```
 app.route('/api/user/cards/:cardId')
   .get(card.read);
 app.param('cardId', card.cardByID);
```

cardByID:

```
exports.cardByID = function (req, res, next, id) {
      Card.findOne({id: id}).exec(function (err, card) {
       if (err) return next(err);
       if (!card) return res.status(404).send({message: 'Карты с таким ID не найдено'});
       req.card = card;
       next();
     });
    };
```

I used to use mongoose _id as param, but need to use other id (8 digits).
It returns 404 status if id is mongoose id type (ex. 57ceda7ec10c15da7c53515f), but if id is just a number (ex. 13241234) it returns 400 status. 
What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

As `MongoDB` says that the `default unique identifier` generated as the primary key `_id` for a document is an `ObjectId`.

---

> And it's  `12-byte binary` value which is often represented as a `24 character hex string`.

And whenever `MongoDB` get less than `24 characters` it does not accept that as `_id`. That's why you are getting some `error` from `MongoDB` side.

Comment: Right, but I am searching not by the field '_id', I search by 'id', it is also unique. It used to work, but after some changes it crushed and I can't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Can you show your single document of a collection? and also show the error which you are getting in `err` variable